# Multi-level sort array of tuples in Swift

Tags: swift, tuples

I want to sort an array of tuples `[(Int,Int)]` based on the `.1` element (from largest to smallest), in case of equality compare `.0` (from smallest to largest)

I am using this :

```
myArray.sort{ $0.0 != $1.0 ? $0.1 > $1.1 : $0.0 < $1.0}
```

but it's not working

Comment: How does the expected output differ from what you're actually seeing?

Comment: after `sort` the myArray is sorted from smallest to largest based on `.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first term in the conditional expression is wrong. If you want to sort on
the .1-component first (in decreasing order) then you have return 
`$0.1 > $1.1` if these elements are different, otherwise compare the .0-components:

This should produce the expected result:

```
myArray.sort{ $0.1 != $1.1 ? $0.1 > $1.1 : $0.0 < $1.0 }
              ============
             difference here
```

Example:

```
var myArray = [ (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)] 
myArray.sort{ $0.1 != $1.1 ? $0.1 > $1.1 : $0.0 < $1.0 }
println(myArray)
// [(1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
```